# Swift 3 escaping closure changes not sticking

Tags: swift, multithreading, closures

I'm attempting to write a Game of Thrones episode compendium using OMDb API. I'm getting the information just fine from the server, but I'm having a difficult time sending that data to my UITableView.

This is both the function calling the closure and the one defining it:

```
func getAllForSeason(season: Int) {
    let uri = "\(baseURL)\(urlId)&season=\(season)"
    var episodeList = [EpisodeModel]()
    let url = URL(string: uri)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print("Error retrieving information. No season found")
      } else {
        if let content = data {
          do {
            let seasonJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
            let episodesFound = seasonJSON?["Episodes"] as! [[String: String]]
            for episodeJSON in episodesFound {
              let number = Int(episodeJSON["Episode"] ?? "0") ?? 0
              var episodeToAdd = EpisodeModel()
              self.getTemporaryEpisode(season: season, number: number, completion: {(result:EpisodeModel) in
                episodeToAdd = result
                print(episodeToAdd.season)
              })
              print(episodeToAdd.season)
              episodeList.append(episodeToAdd)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.delegate?.didGetSeason(episodes: episodeList)
            }
          } catch {
            print ("Error retrieving information. No seasons found")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }


private func getTemporaryEpisode(season: Int, number: Int, completion: @escaping(_ response:EpisodeModel)->Void) {
    let episode = EpisodeModel()
    let uri = "\(baseURL)\(urlId)&season=\(season)&episode=\(number)"
    let url = URL(string: uri)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print("Error downloading episode information. Empty Episode returned")
      } else {
        if let content = data {
          do {
            let episodeJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
            episode.title = (episodeJSON?["Title"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            let dateString = (episodeJSON?["Released"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM dd"
            episode.releaseDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()
            episode.rating = (episodeJSON?["Rated"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            episode.season = Int(episodeJSON?["Season"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0
            episode.number = Int(episodeJSON?["Episode"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0
            let runtimeString = (episodeJSON?["Runtime"] as? String)?.description ?? "0 min"
            let spaceIndex = runtimeString.index(of: " ") ?? runtimeString.endIndex
            let minuteString = runtimeString[runtimeString.startIndex..<spaceIndex]
            episode.minutes = Int(minuteString) ?? 0
            episode.director = (episodeJSON?["Director"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            episode.writer = (episodeJSON?["Writer"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            let actorsString = (episodeJSON?["Actors"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
            episode.actors = actorsString.components(separatedBy: ", ")
            episode.plot = (episodeJSON?["Plot"] as? String)?.description ?? ""
          } catch {
            print("Error downloading episode information. Empty or incomplete episode returned")
          }
        }
      }
      completion(episode)
    }
    task.resume()
  }
```

I have done similar work with the SW API (Star Wars) using the exact same methodology and it worked then.

The print statements placed for testing should both print the season number of the episode obtained with `getTemporaryEpisode`

However, I find instead that while the first print statement prints properly (from within the closure), the second one right outside the closure prints 0 (the default I set in to make sure the value is initialized), meaning that `episodeToAdd` no longer contains the result.

For example: Winter Is Coming will print 1 within the enclosure, but 0 out of it.

It prints the 0s first, so I'm sure it's a threading issue and the completion just hasn't happened by the time the second print statement gets called. I'm just not sure how to solve it.

Edit: I did realize I stupidly placed my call to the main thread inside the loop, but fixing that did not fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getTemporaryEpisode` is asynchronous, so you notify the delegate with an array of empty episodes.

You then reassign the `episodeToAdd` variable to refer to a properly set up episode, but that doesn’t have any effect on the contents of `episodeList`. You probably want to wait to populate `episodeList` until you have retrieved the proper contents. You can use a `DispatchGroup` for this.

However, if you simply use a `DispatchGroup`, the episodes are not required to come back in the expected order, because they’ll each be requested at the same time, independently. The easiest solution would be to gather them in an array and then sort the array by episode number before informing your delegate.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen those before. At a cursory glance though, it looks like you're suggesting each call to `getTemporaryEpisode` should come after something like `dispatchGroup.enter()`, with `dispatchGroup.leave()` within my completion closure, followed by a `dispatchGroup.wait()` at the end of the loop.

If that's correct, I could instead just append to the list I'm sending back in the enclosure, and then once the loop is done sort the array before informing my delegate.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea with the `DispatchGroup`. The point is that the loop will finish before any of the `getTemporaryEpisode` calls invoke their completion handlers. You need the `DispatchGroup.wait()` to prevent the code from continuing until all the completion handlers have returned.